close popup dialog via python
I want to dynamically change the invoke_props_dialog window width based on the showing contents, the way I figured out is to update a global IntProperty to control the window width by calling a new popup window when it changes, the problem I met is that the old window persists(see below picture), anyone knows is there a way to close the old window through python script? Or can I change the original window size instead of instancing a new window? Or any better suggestions to change the popup window size dynamically based on needs?

The dialog window is called in my operator "data_vis.data_select", invoke function, when the window width or column width value changes, I call the operation again to draw a new window.
Call the popup window in the invoke function of the operator:

update the widow size when window width or column width value changes

